# Teradata Date Format

Tags: sql, teradata, informatica

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE SET TABLE test_hold.test_lct ,NO FALLBACK ,
 NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
 NO AFTER JOURNAL,
 DATABLOCKSIZE = 65024 BYTES, CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
 DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
 (
  LCT_NBR SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  RGN_NBR SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  bus_name CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  mail_add CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  city CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  zip CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  OPN_DT DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  CSE_DT DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX I0050PI ( LCT_NBR );
```

The issue I am having is with the two date columns.  After loading records into Teradata from a flat file (which holds dates in YYYY-MM-DD format) using Informatica, I notice that the dates are actually of the format MM/DD/YYYY.

My mapping in Informatica uses a flat file as a source and my Teradata table as a target and simply converts the dates into date/time objects using an expression transformation with the following logic:

```
TO_DATE(i_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The expression doesn't seem to do anything, because if I do not convert the string into a date/time before loading into Teradata I get the same result.

Why would Teradata allow a record that contains a format not specified in the create statement?  I would expect the insert to fail and for there to be no records in the table.

Thank you,

Comment: @Shawn please [edit] your question and describe *The issue I am having* properly: expected results, actual results, sample data, error messages. Also **what did you do?** *Loading from a flat file using informatica* does not say much. And why the 'also' in *which also holds*? You really have to read your question before posting it. Google 'asking good questions'

Comment: So the data loaded fine into the table, but when you `SELECT` one of these records you see a format 'MM/DD/YYYY`?

Comment: Correct, there are no error messages it loads fine but just in the incorrect format. I'm guessing the issue resides in the conversion between an Informatica date/time into a Teradata date that is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Format` keyword is simply used to control how it's displayed.  Different tools can choose to display a date differently depending on the settings in the tool.  Dates are typically stored in some internal representation that's specific to the database.  Using a function like `to_char` will allow you to display the data in the format you want.

[Format](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_109A/ch09.12.20.html#ww979468)

Comment: Thank you sir! You have no idea how long I spent trying to figure this out, tried to mark your answer to accept it but I'm not sure if its working?

Comment: In Teradata the FORMAT is just the *default* format used for casting from/to another datatype.